# Array is being NULL, don't know how

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, variables

trace (suallar); - is written 2 times
1st time - HERE IT SHOWS ALL THE ELEMENTS OF THE ARRAY suallar
2nd time - BUT HERE THIS ARRAY SEEMS TO BE EMPTY, EVEN THOUGH I DIDN'T MANIPULATE WITH IT OR MAKE IT EQUAL TO ANYTHING I MANIPULATE WITH IN BETWEEN

```
var suallar:Array = new Array();
var i:int;
var cavablar:Array=new Array();

suallar.push(["sual1", "duz1", "sehv11", "sevh12", "sevh13","sevh14"]);
suallar.push(["sual2", "duz2", "sehv21", "sevh22","sevh23","sevh24" ]);
suallar.push(["sual3", "duz3", "sehv31", "sevh32","sevh33","sevh34"]);
suallar.push(["sual4", "duz4", "sehv41", "sevh42","sevh43","sevh44"]);
suallar.push(["sual5", "duz5", "sehv51", "sevh52","sevh53","sevh54"]);



var cavablar_temp:Array = suallar.concat();

for (i=0; i<suallar.length; i++){
    cavablar_temp[i].shift();
}

trace (suallar);


for (i=0; i<suallar.length;i++){

var number_array:Array = cavablar_temp[i];

var final_array:Array = [];

var count_selected:int = 5;
for (var u = 0; u < count_selected; u++)
{
    if (number_array.length == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        final_array.push(number_array.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * number_array.length), 1)[0]);

    }   

}
    cavablar.push(final_array);}

trace(cavablar.join("\n"));

trace (suallar);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [Array.splice()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html) documentation:

> Adds elements to and removes elements from an array. This method modifies the array without making a copy.

When you do `number_array.splice()` in the middle of your loop, you're modifying the original arrays you pushed to `suallar`.

Take a look at `Array.slice()`, which returns a new array without modifying the original.

Comment: ok, it deletes elements from number_array and pushes to final_array. but how does it affect the the suallar array?

Comment: suallar is an `Array` of `Array` objects. It only contains references to the `Array` objects and not the actual numbers. When you grab an `Array` object from `suallar` without copying it, then modify it using an in-place operation like `splice()`, this will be reflected in the original `suallar` array (because the `Array` you took from `suallar` is the *exact same* piece of memory you're modifying with `splice`).

Comment: That's right! But, i have written -- var cavablar_temp:Array = suallar.concat(); -- and manipulate with cavablar_temp array after that point :) but still the same.

Comment: When you copy `suallar`, you're just copying a list of references to objects. This is called a shallow copy. The references still point at the same `Array` objects inside `suallar` :)

Comment: Wow! That's true :) Thank you :)
But how can I copy a 2D array, so that i'll have completely new identical and independent array?